# Android SIP call.startAudio() not working

Tags: java, android, sip, voip

I'm making a VoIP program for Android 2.3, so no RTP API, but it should send sound as well. When I call my Android client, everything is fine. However, when I initiate a call from the Android client, the SIP communication works, but no sound at all.
Could anyone help me, please? What I missed?

```
if (this.btnCall.isPressed()) {
  call = manager.makeAudioCall(profile.getUriString(), cdpa, listener, 30);
  call.startAudio();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wait until the call is established. Use the following method in your listener:

```
@Override
public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
   call.startAudio();
   if (call.isMuted()) {
      call.toggleMute();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It happen the same to me,

I solved using adding this to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />

<receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" android:label="Call Receiver" />
```